# Dependency injection with the new .net-core-3 json serializer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I use this contract resolver for dependency-injection with `Autofac` and `Json.NET`:

```cs
public class AutofacContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _container;

    public AutofacContractResolver(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _container = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }

    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);

        // use Autofac to create types that have been registered with it
        if (_container.IsRegistered(objectType))
        {
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => _container.Resolve(objectType);
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then, I use it with DI to initialize the `JsonSerializer`:

```cs
var contractResolver = ctx.Resolve<IContractResolver>(); // ctx = Autofac's IComponentContext

var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer
{
    ContractResolver = contractResolver, // <-- AutofacContractResolver 
};
```

---

What would be the equivalent of this technique with the new [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0) in `net-core-3.0` - if there is any already? I wasn't able to figure this out and couldn't find any *interfaces* that would look similar to this ones.

Comment: This is interesting. I am not sure if something like this is built into it as yet.

Comment: @Nkosi I was afraid someone might say this. This would be a big show-stopper. I hope they'll implement something in the long run.

Comment: The equivalent types in `System.Text.Json` -- [`JsonClassInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonClassInfo.cs) and [`JsonPropertyInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonPropertyInfo.cs) -- are **internal**.  There is an open enhancement [Equivalent of DefaultContractResolver in System.Text.Json #42001](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42001) asking for a public equivalent.

Comment: Related or duplicate: [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182) which is also unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this library I wrote as an extension to System.Text.Json to offer missing features: https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Json.

You will find support for programmatic object mapping.

Define your own implementation of IObjectMappingConvention:

```
public class AutofacObjectMappingConvention : IObjectMappingConvention
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _container;

    public AutofacObjectMappingConvention(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _container = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
    }


    public void Apply<T>(JsonSerializerOptions options, ObjectMapping<T> objectMapping) where T : class
    {
        defaultObjectMappingConvention.Apply<T>(options, objectMapping);

        // use Autofac to create types that have been registered with it
        if (_container.IsRegistered(objectType))
        {
            objectMapping.MapCreator(o => _container.Resolve<T>());
        }
    }
}
```

Implement IObjectMappingConventionProvider to associate more than one type to the convention:

```
public class AutofacObjectMappingConventionProvider : IObjectMappingConventionProvider
{
    public IObjectMappingConvention GetConvention(Type type)
    {
        // here you could filter which type should be instantiated by autofac and return null for other types
        return new AutofacObjectMappingConvention();
    }
}
```

Setup json extensions by calling on JsonSerializerOptions the extension method SetupExtensions defined in the namespace Dahomey.Json:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.SetupExtensions();
```

Register the new object mapping convention for the class:

```
options.GetObjectMappingConventionRegistry().RegisterProvider(new AutofacObjectMappingConventionProvider());
```

Then serialize your class with the regular Sytem.Text.Json API:

```
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(myClass, options);
```