# System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serialization, system.text.json

In the new System.Text.Json; namespace is there something like IContractResolver i am trying to migrate my project away from Newtonsoft.

This is one of the classes i am trying to move:

```
public class SelectiveSerializer : DefaultContractResolver
{
private readonly string[] fields;

public SelectiveSerializer(string fields)
{
  var fieldColl = fields.Split(',');
  this.fields = fieldColl
      .Select(f => f.ToLower().Trim())
      .ToArray();
}

protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
  var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
  property.ShouldSerialize = o => fields.Contains(member.Name.ToLower());

  return property;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you use .net core 3.0?Could you share why do you want to migrate from `Newtonsoft` to `System.Text.Json`?Actually,net core 3.0 could support `Newtonsoft`.And how did your code work?Is is used to lower case the body data?

Comment: @Rena This code was used for building our own select function for api. example: select=FirstName,Email,Id serializer would only serialize specified fields. Similar to how odata does it since we are moving away from odata

Comment: The equivalent types in `System.Text.Json` -- [`JsonClassInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonClassInfo.cs) and [`JsonPropertyInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonPropertyInfo.cs) -- are **internal**.  There is an open enhancement [Equivalent of DefaultContractResolver in System.Text.Json #42001](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42001) asking for a public equivalent.

Comment: @dbc good to know :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The equivalent types in System.Text.Json -- [`JsonClassInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonClassInfo.cs) and [`JsonPropertyInfo`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonPropertyInfo.cs) -- are **internal**. There is an open enhancement
> [Equivalent of DefaultContractResolver in System.Text.Json #31257](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31257)
> asking for a public equivalent. – dbc Nov 25 at 19:11

Github issues:

- [Open up metadata infrastructure of System.Text.Json #34456](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/34456)
- [Equivalent of DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties override in System.Text.Json #60518](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/60518)
- [Equivalent of DefaultContractResolver in System.Text.Json #31257](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31257)

**Please try this:**
I wrote this as an extension to System.Text.Json to offer missing features: https://github.com/dahomey-technologies/Dahomey.Json.

You will find support for programmatic object mapping.

Define your own implementation of IObjectMappingConvention:

```
public class SelectiveSerializer : IObjectMappingConvention
{
    private readonly IObjectMappingConvention defaultObjectMappingConvention = new DefaultObjectMappingConvention();
    private readonly string[] fields;

    public SelectiveSerializer(string fields)
    {
        var fieldColl = fields.Split(',');
        this.fields = fieldColl
            .Select(f => f.ToLower().Trim())
            .ToArray();
    }

    public void Apply<T>(JsonSerializerOptions options, ObjectMapping<T> objectMapping) where T : class
    {
        defaultObjectMappingConvention.Apply<T>(options, objectMapping);
        foreach (IMemberMapping memberMapping in objectMapping.MemberMappings)
        {
            if (memberMapping is MemberMapping<T> member)
            {
                member.SetShouldSerializeMethod(o => fields.Contains(member.MemberName.ToLower()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Define your class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Setup json extensions by calling on JsonSerializerOptions the extension method SetupExtensions defined in the namespace Dahomey.Json:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.SetupExtensions();
```

Register the new object mapping convention for the class:

```
options.GetObjectMappingConventionRegistry().RegisterConvention(
    typeof(Employee), new SelectiveSerializer("FirstName,Email,Id"));
```

Then serialize your class with the regular Sytem.Text.Json API:

```
Employee employee = new Employee
{
    Id = 12,
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Email = "john.doe@acme.com"
};
        
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(employee, options);
// {"Id":12,"FirstName":"John","Email":"john.doe@acme.com"};
```

Answer (score 5):

**Contract customization will be implemented in .NET 7, and is available in [Preview 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7-preview-6/#json-contract-customization).**

From the documentation page *[What’s new in System.Text.Json in .NET 7: Contract Customization](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#contract-customization)* by Eirik Tsarpalis, Krzysztof Wicher and Layomi Akinrinade:

> The contract metadata for a given type `T` is represented using [`JsonTypeInfo<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinfo-1?view=net-7.0), which in previous versions served as an opaque token used exclusively in source generator APIs. Starting in .NET 7, most facets of the `JsonTypeInfo` contract metadata have been exposed and made user-modifiable.  Contract customization allows users to write their own JSON contract resolution logic using implementations of the [`IJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.ijsontypeinforesolver) interface:
>
> ```
> public interface IJsonTypeInfoResolver
> {
>     JsonTypeInfo? GetTypeInfo(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options);
> }
> ```
>
> A contract resolver returns a configured `JsonTypeInfo` instance for the given `Type` and `JsonSerializerOptions` combination. It can return null if the resolver does not support metadata for the specified input type.
>
> Contract resolution performed by the default, reflection-based serializer is now exposed via the [`DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver?view=net-7.0) class, which implements `IJsonTypeInfoResolver`.
>
> Starting from .NET 7 the [`JsonSerializerContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonserializercontext?view=net-7.0) class used in source generation also implements `IJsonTypeInfoResolver`.

You can create your own `IJsonTypeInfoResolver` via one of the following methods:

1. You can subclass `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` and override [`GetTypeInfo(Type, JsonSerializerOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.gettypeinfo?view=net-7.0).  This resembles overriding Json.NET's [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateContract.htm).
2. You can add an `Action<JsonTypeInfo>` to [`DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver.Modifiers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to modify the default [`JsonTypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinfo?view=net-7.0) generated for selected types after creation.

   Combining multiple customizations looks easier with this approach than with the inheritance approach. However, since the modifier actions are applied in order, there is a chance that later modifiers could conflict with earlier modifiers.
3. You could create your own `IJsonTypeInfoResolver` from scratch that creates contracts only for those types that interest you, and combine it with some other type info resolver via [`JsonTypeInfoResolver.Combine(IJsonTypeInfoResolver[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinforesolver.combine?view=net-7.0).

   `JsonTypeInfoResolver.Combine()` is also useful when you want to use compile-time generated `JsonSerializerContext` instances with a runtime contract resolver that customizes serialization for certain types only.

Once you have a custom resolver, you can set it via [`JsonSerializerOptions.TypeInfoResolver`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.typeinforesolver?view=net-7.0).

Thus your `SelectiveSerializer` can be converted to a `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` roughly as follows, using modifiers.  First define the following fluent extension methods:

```
public static partial class JsonSerializerExtensions
{
    public static DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver SerializeSelectedFields(this DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver resolver, string fields) =>
        SerializeSelectedFields(resolver, fields?.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries) ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fields)));

    public static DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver SerializeSelectedFields(this DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver resolver, IEnumerable<string> membersToSerialize)
    {
        if (resolver == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resolver));
        if (membersToSerialize == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(membersToSerialize));
        var membersToSerializeSet =  membersToSerialize.ToHashSet(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase); // Possibly this should be changed to StringComparer.Ordinal
        resolver.Modifiers.Add(typeInfo => 
                               {
                                   if (typeInfo.Kind == JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                                   {
                                       foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
                                       {
                                           if (property.GetMemberName() is {} name && !membersToSerializeSet.Contains(name))
                                               property.ShouldSerialize = static (obj, value) => false;
                                       }
                                   }
                               });
        return resolver;
    }
    
    public static string? GetMemberName(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo)?.Name;
}
```

And now you can set up your `JsonSerializerOptions` e.g. as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()
        .SerializeSelectedFields("FirstName,Email,Id"),
    // Add other options as required
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase, 
    WriteIndented = true,
};
```

Notes:

- [`JsonPropertyInfo.ShouldSerialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.shouldserialize?view=net-7.0) (also [new in .NET 7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#example-conditional-serialization)) can be used for conditional serialization of properties.
- When a `JsonPropertyInfo` was created by the reflection or source-gen resolvers, [`JsonPropertyInfo.AttributeProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.attributeprovider?view=net-7.0) will be the underlying `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo`.

  For confirmation see [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77761#issuecomment-1299657813) by layomia to [System.Text.Json: In .NET 7, how can I determine the JsonPropertyInfo created for a specific member, so I can customize the serialization of that member? #77761](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77761).
- All serialization metadata should be constructed using locale-invariant string logic.  In your code you use `ToLower()` but it would have been better to use [`ToLowerInvariant()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tolowerinvariant?view=net-7.0).  In my modifier action I use `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` which avoids the need to lowercase the strings.
- System.Text.Json is case-sensitive by default so you might want to use case-sensitive property name matching when filtering selected fields.

Comment: Note - not tested yet, will test when .NET 7 is released.

Comment: .net 7 has since been released and this feature is described here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#example-conditional-serialization