# DefaultContractResolver equivalent in System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

I am converting some logic from Newtonsoft and found one of following implementation

```
 public class CustomDataContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> FieldNameChanges { get; set; }
        public List<FieldValueReplica> FieldValueReplica { get; set; }

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            if (property.DeclaringType != typeof(logEvent)) return property;

            if (FieldNameChanges.Count > 0 && FieldNameChanges.TryGetValue(property.PropertyName, out var newValue))
                property.PropertyName = newValue;
            
            return property;
        }
   }
```

Any one have converted DefaultContractResolver to System.Text.Json

Comment: There is none that is public.  See: [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182).

Comment: :( Thanks  dbc. Then could anyone help in above logic conversion to System.Text.Json

Comment: You would need to create a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) for `logEvent`.  Alternatively, the linked question has an answer that suggests some third party extension that might do the job, but I haven't tried it so I can't say one way or the other.

Comment: no problem dbc. i am checking that link. may be some other guy have done similar and help in it

Comment: .NET 7 now provides custom contract resolvers.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74284215/3744182) to [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182).  Does that answer your question, or do you need a specific answer?