# System.Text.Json - Use custom JsonConverter conditionally depending on field attribute

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, system.text.json

I have a custom attribute `[Foo]`
implemented as follows:

```
public class FooAttribute
  : Attribute
{
}
```

Now I want to use the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` to step into each field that has that attribute, in order to manipulate how is serialized and deserialized.

For example, if I have the following class

```
class SampleInt
{
    [Foo] 
    public int Number { get; init; }

    public int StandardNumber { get; init; }

    public string Text { get; init; }
}
```

when I serialize an instance of this class, I want a custom *int* `JsonConverter` to apply only for that field.

```
public class IntJsonConverter
    : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override int Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // do whatever before reading if the text starts with "potato". But this should be triggered only if destination type has the Foo attribute. How?
        return reader.GetInt32();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue("potato" + value.ToString());
    }
}
```

so that the serialization for

```
var sample =
  new SampleInt
  {
    Number = 123,
    StandardNumber = 456
    Text = "bar"
};
```

like this

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions();
var serializeOptions.Converters.Add(new IntJsonConverter());
var resultJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(sample, serializeOptions);
```

results on the following json

```
{
  "number": "potato123",
  "standardNumber": 456,
  "text": "bar"
}
```

and not in

```
{
  "number": "potato123",
  "standardNumber": "potato456",
  "text": "bar"
}
```

In a similar manner, I want the deserialization to be conditional, and only use the custom converter if the destination field has the `[Foo]` attribute.

With *Newtonsoft*, this is possible using Contract Resolvers and overriding `CreateProperties` method like this.

```
public class SerializationContractResolver
    : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private readonly ICryptoTransform _encryptor;
    private readonly FieldEncryptionDecryption _fieldEncryptionDecryption;

    public SerializationContractResolver(
        ICryptoTransform encryptor,
        FieldEncryptionDecryption fieldEncryptionDecryption)
    {
        _encryptor = encryptor;
        _fieldEncryptionDecryption = fieldEncryptionDecryption;
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy();
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        foreach (var jsonProperty in properties)
        {
            var hasAttribute = HasAttribute(type, jsonProperty);
            if (hasAttribute)
            {
                var serializationJsonConverter = new MyJsonConverter();
                jsonProperty.Converter = serializationJsonConverter;
            }
        }
        return properties;
    }
    
    private bool HasAttribute(Type type, JsonProperty jsonProperty)
    {
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(jsonProperty.UnderlyingName);
        if (propertyInfo is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var hasAttribute =
            propertyInfo.CustomAttributes
                .Any(x => x.AttributeType == typeof(FooAttribute));
        var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        var isSimpleValue = propertyType.IsValueType || propertyType == typeof(string);
        var isSupportedField = isSimpleValue && hasPersonalDataAttribute;
        return isSupportedField;
    }
}
```

But I don't want to use Newtonsoft. I want to use the new dotnet `System.Text.Json` serializer. Is it possible to use it in a similar granular way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64729381/defaultcontractresolver-equivalent-in-system-text-json and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58926112/system-text-json-api-is-there-something-like-icontractresolver and https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36785 are relevant.

Comment: Apparently on .net 7 :/