# How do I add lexicographical sort in this System.Text.Json serialization way?

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I'm implementing an exchange which has private endpoints which are protected with a signature. The first code looks better but it results into an invalid signature due to the fact that it doesn't lexicographically sort it. How do I fix it? The second code works fine btw.

- Official Java example - [here](https://github.com/mxcdevelop/mexc-api-demo/blob/7991f8a3a17e6ba5dc2cf55133532ab145b0c878/Java/src/main/java/com/mexc/example/spot/websocket/MexcSpotRawWsExample.java#L84-L90)
- [Docs](https://github.com/mxcdevelop/APIDoc/blob/master/websocket/spot/websocket.2022_2_28.md#%E8%8E%B7%E5%8F%96%E8%B4%A6%E6%88%B7%E8%AE%A2%E5%8D%95%E7%8A%B6%E6%80%81%E6%8E%A8%E9%80%81-get-account-order-status-push)

### Broken code

```cs
public ValueTask SubscribeToPrivateAsync()
{
    var request = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MexcSubPersonalPayload(_apiKey, _apiSecret));

    return SendAsync(request);
}

internal class MexcSubPersonalPayload
{
    private readonly string _apiSecret;

    public MexcSubPersonalPayload(string apiKey, string apiSecret)
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
        _apiSecret = apiSecret;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("op")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
    public string Operation => "sub.personal";

    [JsonPropertyName("api_key")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
    public string ApiKey { get; }

    [JsonPropertyName("sign")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(3)]
    public string Signature => Sign(ToString());

    [JsonPropertyName("req_time")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(4)]
    public long RequestTime => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

    private string Sign(string payload)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(payload))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        using var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
        return Convert.ToHexString(hash);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"api_key={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ApiKey)}&req_time={RequestTime}&op={Operation}&api_secret={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_apiSecret)}";
    }
}
```

## Working code

```cs
public ValueTask SubscribeToPrivateAsync()
{
    var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
    var @params = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "api_key", _apiKey },
        { "req_time", now },
        { "op", "sub.personal" }
    };

    var signature = SignatureHelper.Sign(SignatureHelper.GenerateSign(@params, _apiSecret));
    var request = new PersonalRequest("sub.personal", _apiKey, signature, now);

    return SendAsync(request);
}

internal static class SignatureHelper
{
    public static string GenerateSign(IDictionary<string, object> query, string apiSecret)
    {
        // Lexicographic order
        query = new SortedDictionary<string, object>(query, StringComparer.Ordinal);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var queryParameterString = string.Join("&",
            query.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kvp.Value.ToString()))
                .Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value.ToString())}"));
        sb.Append(queryParameterString);

        if (sb.Length > 0)
        {
            sb.Append('&');
        }

        sb.Append("api_secret=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(apiSecret));

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static string Sign(string source)
    {
        using var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var sourceBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(sourceBytes);
        return Convert.ToHexString(hash);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are your [`JsonPropertyOrder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties#configure-the-order-of-serialized-properties) attributes not in lexicographical order?  Defining property order via this attribute is currently the only way to control property order during serialization with System.Text.Json as its [contract information is private](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182).

Comment: If you can't use `JsonPropertyOrder` to configure the order as required (e.g. because you require different orders in different contexts) you could either 1) Use a custom converter to inject a DTO with the properties in the required order, or 2) Serialize to `JsonObject` and sort that (recursively if needed).  Do either 1 or 2 meet your needs?

Comment: @dbc, yes, probably a custom converter suits it more. But it would be nice to hear both solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update for .NET 7**

In .NET 7 and later you may use a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to lexicographically sort the JSON properties of your your type's [JSON contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts).

First, define the following static methods returning an `Action<JsonTypeInfo>`:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> AlphabetizeProperties(Type type)
    {
        return typeInfo =>
        {
            if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object || !type.IsAssignableFrom(typeInfo.Type))
                return;
            AlphabetizeProperties()(typeInfo);
        };
    }
    
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> AlphabetizeProperties()
    {
        return static typeInfo =>
        {
            if (typeInfo.Kind != JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                return;
            var properties = typeInfo.Properties.OrderBy(p => p.Name, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();
            typeInfo.Properties.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
            {
                properties[i].Order = i;
                typeInfo.Properties.Add(properties[i]);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And now you will be able to serialize as follows:

```
var payload = new MexcSubPersonalPayload(_apiKey, _apiSecret);
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
    {
        Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.AlphabetizeProperties() },
    },
};
var request = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload, options);
```

Notes:

- Overflow properties stored in an [extension data dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/handle-overflow?pivots=dotnet-7-0#handle-overflow-json) will not be alphabetized using this method.  System.Text.Json seems to always place them last.

  This does not apply to your `MexcSubPersonalPayload` model.
- This approach does not apply to dictionary serialization.  To order the dictionary properties when serializing, a custom converter could be used.

  This also does not apply to your `MexcSubPersonalPayload` model.

.NET 7 demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UTJ1GB).

**Original Answer for .NET 6 and earlier**

As explained in *[Configure the order of serialized properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties#configure-the-order-of-serialized-properties)*, as of .NET 6 the only mechanism that System.Text.Json provides to control property order during serialization is to apply [`[JsonPropertyOrder]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertyorderattribute) attributes to your model <sup>[1]</sup>.  You have already done so -- but the order specified is not lexicographic.  So what are your options?

Firstly, you could modify your model so that the `[JsonPropertyOrder]` are in lexicographic order:

```
internal class MexcSubPersonalPayload
{
    private readonly string _apiSecret;

    public MexcSubPersonalPayload(string apiKey, string apiSecret)
    {
        ApiKey = apiKey;
        _apiSecret = apiSecret;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("op")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
    public string Operation => "sub.personal";

    [JsonPropertyName("api_key")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
    public string ApiKey { get; }

    [JsonPropertyName("sign")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(4)]
    public string Signature => Sign(ToString());

    [JsonPropertyName("req_time")]
    [JsonPropertyOrder(3)]
    public long RequestTime => DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();

    // Remainder unchanged
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M8t9K4).

Secondly, if you cannot modify your `[JsonPropertyOrder]` attributes (because e.g. you require a different order in a different context), then as long as you are using .NET 6 or later, you could serialize your model to an intermediate [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0) hierarchy and sort its properties before finally formatting as a JSON string.  To do this, first introduce the following extension methods:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonNode? SortProperties(this JsonNode? node, bool recursive = true) => node.SortProperties(StringComparer.Ordinal, recursive);

    public static JsonNode? SortProperties(this JsonNode? node, IComparer<string> comparer, bool recursive = true)
    {
        if (node is JsonObject obj)
        {
            var properties = obj.ToList();
            obj.Clear();
            foreach (var pair in properties.OrderBy(p => p.Key, comparer))
                obj.Add(new (pair.Key, recursive ? pair.Value.SortProperties(comparer, recursive) : pair.Value));
        }
        else if (node is JsonArray array)
        {
            foreach (var n in array)
                n.SortProperties(comparer, recursive);
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to do:

```
public string GenerateRequest() => JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(new MexcSubPersonalPayload(_apiKey, _apiSecret))
    .SortProperties(StringComparer.Ordinal)!
    .ToJsonString();
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mt0tKO).

Thirdly, you could create a [custom `JsonConverter<MexcSubPersonalPayload>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) that serializes the properties in the correct order, e.g. by mapping `MexcSubPersonalPayload` to a DTO, then serializing the DTO.  First define:

```
class MexcSubPersonalPayloadConverter : JsonConverter<MexcSubPersonalPayload>
{
    record MexcSubPersonalPayloadDTO(
        [property:JsonPropertyName("api_key"), JsonPropertyOrder(1)] string ApiKey, 
        [property:JsonPropertyName("op"), JsonPropertyOrder(2)] string Operation, 
        [property:JsonPropertyName("req_time"), JsonPropertyOrder(3)]long RequestTime, 
        [property:JsonPropertyName("sign"), JsonPropertyOrder(4)]string Signature);

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MexcSubPersonalPayload value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, new MexcSubPersonalPayloadDTO(value.ApiKey, value.Operation, value.RequestTime, value.Signature), options);
    public override MexcSubPersonalPayload Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

And then do:

```
public string GenerateRequest() => JsonSerializer.Serialize(new MexcSubPersonalPayload(_apiKey, _apiSecret), new JsonSerializerOptions { Converters = { new MexcSubPersonalPayloadConverter() }});
```

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BnWN1n).

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> With Json.NET one could override property order via a custom contract resolver, but as of .NET 6 System.Text.Json lacks this flexibility as its [contract information is private](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112/3744182).</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This results into `{"api_key":"mx0ETo1oU5o7v6M7dH","op":"sub.personal","req_time":1655052021218,"sign":"efbd96be2362ce18557b573b31eb72c7"}` which results into an invalid signature. The working code outputs the following: `{"api_key":"mx0ETo1oU5o7v6M7dH","sign":"e3a206c4bf9af6c365ed3969730d533a","req_time":1655052021100,"op":"sub.personal"}`

Comment: Oh I think I know what the issue is. It should be sorted in lexicographical order before it gets the signature (before `Sign(...)` call)

Comment: @nop - your broken code didn't show the JSON being passed into `Sign()`, just a URL-encoded string with some properties.  So I couldn't test or demo that.  If you want to pass your JSON into `Sign()` please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72592246/edit) your original question to show what you need to do -- i.e. a [mcve] where you need to generate the sorted JSON for signing.

Comment: I'm not sure tbh. https://github.com/mxcdevelop/mexc-api-demo/blob/7991f8a3a17e6ba5dc2cf55133532ab145b0c878/go/ws/private/privateWs.go this is a Go working sample, it looks like they are doing the same as in your code but it doesn't work (invalid signature)

Comment: @nop - Incidentally if you are trying to recursively serialize to JSON to generate a signature while inside JSON serialization you are going to have bigger problems because System.Text.Json doesn't support recursive self-serialization easily.  (Also, I don't know Go so I can't compare that code with mine.)

Comment: got it working. `ToString` had to be as following: `return $"api_key={ApiKey}&op={Operation}&req_time={RequestTime}&api_secret={_apiSecret}";`

Comment: @nop - Incidentally, since you timestamp your objects with `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` it's difficult for me to know whether the generated signatures are correct.  If you are going to create a [mcve] maybe you could use a dummy fixed value so we can see consistent signatures?

Comment: https://github.com/mxcdevelop/mexc-api-demo/blob/7991f8a3a17e6ba5dc2cf55133532ab145b0c878/go/ws/private/privateWs.go#L35 take a look at this one. Since `Sign(...)` is being called with what's in `ToString`, the order doesn't really matter as soon as what's in `ToString` is correct. Basically I made it like their Go example

Comment: here is the working code btw: https://pastebin.com/qtVpMjhc Thank you very much! You can update your answer if you'd like to

Comment: @nop - so in the end, did you need to sort the JSON properties at all?  Your working code doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: nope. I had to manually sort what's in `ToString()`. If there has to be any sorting, it should be applied on the `ToString()`

Comment: @nop - Oh well.  I did answer the general question *How to override the property order in System.Text.Json* though, so I guess it's worth leaving the answer here, even if you didn't actually need that.