# How to set JsonSerializerOption per request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, system.text.json, .net-7.0

I have a .NET 7 web api with a route that returns Users.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public String? Name { get; set; }
    public Int32? Age { get; set; }
    public String? HairColor { get; set; }
}
```

If "Name" comes in the `Select` query param, the database only returns the Name property and the `Ok(users);` returns.  Ex:

```
[
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Test1",
        "age": null,
        "hairColor": null
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Test2",
        "age": null,
        "hairColor": null
    },
    {
        "id": null,
        "name": "Test3",
        "age": null,
        "hairColor": null,
    }
]
```

To save on package size, I would instead like it to return:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test2"
    },
    {
        "name": "Test3"
    }
]
```

But, if nothing comes in the `Select` query param, all of the properties get populated and returned even if null/default.  How can I dynamically set

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault
};
```

So that if `Select` is set, Ok(users) ignores the null/default properties when serializing, otherwise it returns all properties?

Comment: Can’t you just return an anonymous object that just projects the `Name` property?

Comment: A newtonsoft contract resolver can filter / ignore properties, which you could customise per request. I don't think there is a system.text equivalent. The closest would be a custom converter, but you'll have to implement the low level json reading / writing.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - In .NET 7 System.Text.Json made its contract resolver public, see [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74284215/3744182).  Main issue looks to be how to use different options for specific requests as the question states.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the simpliest way is

```
    if (users[0].Id != null) return Ok(users); //or more validations
    return Ok( users.Select(u => new { Name = u.Name }) );
```

Comment: Utilizing an anonymous type is interesting. I would need to make the creation of it dynamic as I don't know what property names are being sent in. I suppose I could check if `Select` has value, and if so, loop through the values and use reflection to pull those properties from the model and put them into this anonymous object.

Comment: @ScubaSteve  "as I don't know what property names are being sent in."? What do you mean? In  your question you wrote you had a list of users.

Comment: The database is returning a list of users, yes.  But, what property names are in `Select` is dynamic.  So, the requestor may leave it null, meaning all properties of User are returned for each User.  Or, for example, it could have Age and HairColor, in which only those properties would be returned for each User.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but utilizing anonymous types was a spark. I thought, I would need to dynamically and recursively find all of the properties in `Select`, then add it to the anonymous type.  Instead of reinventing the wheel, why not just utilize System.Text.Json?

```
if (select is not null && select.Count > 0)
{
    var modelsWithLessProperties = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object>(JsonSerializer.Serialize(models, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault
    }));

    return Ok(modelsWithLessProperties);
}

return Ok(models);
```

Serializing, then deserializing may not be the most efficient way of doing this, but it is utilizing established code.

I am open to any, more efficient, established (i.e. not error prone) way of doing this.