# How can I exclude properties from JSON serialization using custom logic in System.Text.Json without using attribute?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have an object that contains a `Func` property:

```
public class Foo {
   public Func<int> DoCalculation {get;init;}
   public string Bar {get;init;}
}
```

How can I exclude all `Func<...>` properties in any JSON serialization without using `[JsonIgnore]` or any other attribute?

Context:

- System.Text.JSON
- .net core 6

Comment: Youb can consider [`[DataMember]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#what-gets-serialized) However, it depends on your scenario and requirement because you are `using Func<int>` deligate within your class. Thus, need to know more details what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, I'm looking for a solution without using an attribute of any kind.

Comment: Take a look at [System.Text.Json API is there something like IContractResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58926112).  In .NET 7 you will be able to use a [TypeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts#modifiers) to exclude properties by type.  But in .NET 6 this is not available so you will need to write a custom converter or use a 3rd party library like Dahomey.Json.  In fact I'd say your question is a duplicate of that one, agree?